# What are the limitations of fighting in a guest campaign?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Can I still gain Alliance Points? Will I gain bonus points for helping take/defend a keep? I know I'm not enterd into the points race, but can I still do the repeatable quests? Can I capture/carry Elder Scrolls? Can I do all the other stuff that I haven't even thought of yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only real difference between a Guest Campaign and your Home Campaign is the fact that you won't appear on the Leaderboards and that you'll only carry your Home Campaign's bonuses outside Cyrodiil. That's it. You'll get your Alliance Points as usual, for whatever you're doing.